# Stack level too deep on upgrading rails 3.1.10 to 3.2.0

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2, actiondispatch, actionpack, rails-upgrade, stack-level

I am getting the following errors after upgrading my rails application from `3.1.10` to `3.2.0`.
`rails console` is opening fine. And, I am able to execute code in console. However, When I run `rails server` and open page in `browser`. It fails and shows the following errors.

SystemStackError (stack level too deep):
  actionpack (3.2.21) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:70

`Rendered /home/sarwan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551@project-name/gems/actionpack-3.2.21/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.erb (0.8ms)`
  `Rendered /home/sarwan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551@project-name/gems/actionpack-3.2.21/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_request_and_response.erb (0.7ms)`
  `Rendered /home/sarwan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551@project-name/gems/actionpack-3.2.21/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/diagnostics.erb within rescues/layout (13.8ms)`
Cache read: http://localhost:3000/favicon.ico?

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Did you make the changes to your gem file?  https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/upgrading_ruby_on_rails.html#upgrading-from-rails-3-1-to-rails-3-2

Comment: Can you try rails server -p 3000